# Converting letter vector into numeric vector

Tags: r

If I want to convert the letter vector c("A","B","C") into c(10,20,30), what function could I use?

Sorry for asking a question that seems to be trivial. I am a self-taught beginner and I am still getting familiar with the functions.

Edit:

I explain why I ask such strange question.

So here is the background:

A standard deck of playing cards can be created in R as a data frame with the following
command.

Note that D =  Diamond, C =  Club, H =  Heart, S =  Spade

```
deck <- data.frame(
suit = rep(c("D","C","H","S"), 13),

rank = rep(2:14, 4)
11 = Jack, 12 = Queen, 13 = King, 14 = Ace
)
```

A poker hand is a set of five playing cards. Sample a poker hand using the data frame
deck and name it as hand.

```
hand<-deck[sample(nrow(deck),5),]
hand
```

A flush is a hand that contains five cards all of the same suit. Create a logical value named
is.flush which is TRUE if and only if hand is a flush.

```
is.flush<-length(unique(hand[,1]))==1
is.flush
```

And here starts the problem:

"A straight is a hand that contains five cards of sequential rank. Note that both

A K Q J 10 and 5 4 3 2 A are considered to be straight, but Q K A 2 3 is
not. Create a logical value named is. straight which is TRUE if and only if the hand is
straight."
Hint: The all() function could be useful.

So here is my attepmt:

I can set:

```
y <- read.table(text = "
2 3 4 5 6
3 4 5 6 7
4 5 6 7 8
5 6 7 8 9
6 7 8 9 10")

apply(y, 1, function(x) all(diff(sort(x[ x != 2 ])) == 1))
```

Then I can have a TRUE FALSE value.

But I cannot input letters in the function above.

Hence I am stuck here, and I have to convert the letter to numbers.

(Unless there is a smarter way)

P.S.

The background code I have so far:

```
deck <- data.frame(
suit = rep(c("D","C","H","S"), 13),
rank = rep(2:14, 4)
) 
deck

hand<-deck[sample(nrow(deck),5),]
hand

is.flush<-length(unique(hand[,1]))==1
is.flush
```

Comment: What's the relationship between the letters and numbers?

Comment: Could it be entirely no relationship? That's why I wonder if there is a way to define such function to map c("A","B","C") to c(10,20,30)

Comment: What is the purpose of such approach ? Do you intend to apply it to a large vector containing repated A, B, C, ... items ?

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Comment: I want to reopen a new post (But have to wait for 90 mins) since the content is already far from the original post. My apologies for my misbehavior.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want `case_when` inside a custom function

```
library(tidyverse)

my_func <- function(letter) { 
      case_when(letter == 'A' ~ 10,
                letter == 'B' ~ 20,
                letter == 'C' ~ 30, 
                TRUE ~ 0)
      }
my_func(c("A","B","C"))
```

Will give you

```
[1] 10 20 30
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to map each letter to an arbitrary output value, you can use a named vector as a dictionary, for example:

```
dictionary <- (1:26) * 10          # 10, 20, 30 .. 260
names(dictionary) <- LETTERS       # built-in vector of uppercase letters
dictionary
  A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L   M   N   O   P   Q   R   S   T   U   V 
 10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90 100 110 120 130 140 150 160 170 180 190 200 210 220 
  W   X   Y   Z 
230 240 250 260
```

You can then use letters to index the dictionary and return the mapped value:

```
test <- c("B", "L", "A")
dictionary[test]
  B   L   A 
 20 120  10
```

The function that is actually performing the mapping here is the `[` operator, see the [Extract](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.html) docs.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
library(tidyverse)

x <- c("A","B","C") 

recode(x, A = 10, B = 20, C = 30, .default = 0)
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.